# URL modification/rewriting

Tags: url, url-rewriting

I wonder how its possible to make it compatible for both OS depending if I host my website on windows or linux

for an example of a link that should be rewritten:
OLD: yourdomain.org/index.php?menu=register&action=create
NEW: yourdomain.org/index/register/create

I'm sorry if this is not the correct board or something, I hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work it will rewrite your url

http://yourdomain.org/index.php?menu=register&action=create

to

http://yourdomain.org/index/register/create

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?menu=$1&action=$2 [L]`

Comment: im using xampp on windows at the moment, and it seems nothing happens.. I added .htaccess to my htdocs folder

Comment: Are you trying to get redirect rule and have you configured your app to follow these rules?